# PHP WebDriver assert a condition?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

I created a test using PHP WebDriver and Selenium. Now I want to make sure that a certain text is contained in an element. How do I do that? I tried:

```
$web_driver->wait(3)->until(
  WebDriverExpectedCondition::textToBePresentInElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('.cart-price span.price'), '55,00 €')
  );
```

But this always ends in a TimeoutException. Isnt there a way to really use something like this:

```
assertTrue(WebDriverExpectedCondition::textToBePresentInElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('.cart-price span.price'), '55,00 €'))
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$web_driver->wait(3)->until(
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::textToBePresentInElement(
      WebDriverBy::cssSelector('.cart-price span.price'), '55,00 €'
    )
);
```

is already the `assertTrue` to me. It throws the `TimeoutException` if it cannot find the element containing certain text within 3 seconds.

If you are seeing the text on the browser, it might happen that there is no element found by the `WebDriverBy` or there are more than one element and the driver is getting another element which match the `WebDriverBy`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PHP, you might have to change the

```
max_execution_time
```

in your PHP.ini file.

This sets the number of seconds that a PHP script can run for.

Comment: This won't work. The TimeoutException is thrown because the $driver fails to wait for the element with certain text in 3 seconds. It is not the PHP script timeout.